# Show that B is singular

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a linear algebra problem concerning singularity and linear independence.

A is an $n \times n-1$ matrix where $A=\{A_1,A_2,...,A_{n-1}\}$

Show that $B$ is singular if $B=\{A_1,A_2,...,A_{n-1},Ab\}$ for every choice $b$ in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$

Answer (score 1):

The set 
$$
B=\{A_1,A_2,...,A_{n-1},Ab\}\subset\mathbb R^{n-1},
$$
contains $n$ elements of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. But $\dim \mathbb R^{n-1}=n-1$, and hence any $n$ elements of
$\mathbb R^{n-1}$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

$B$ is singular because its columns are not independent: with $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_{n-1})'$, we have:
$$
(-b_1)A_1+(-b_2)A_2+\cdots+(-b_{n-1})A_{n-1}+(1)Ab=0.
$$